# How to exclude a field in @SqlResultSetMapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity **BestSellerMagazines** with custom **@SqlResultSetMapping**

```
 @Entity
 @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "BestSellerMagazinesJobQueryMapping",
    entities = {@EntityResult(entityClass = BestSellerMagazines.class, fields = {
            @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "[ID]"),
            @FieldResult(name = "groupId", column = "[GroupID]")
    })}
)
public class BestSellerMagazines implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "GroupID")
    private Integer groupId;

    @Column(name = "ZoneId")
    private Integer zoneId;
}
```

As you can see, the **@SqlResultSetMapping** doesn't have *zoneId* field, but **BestSellerMagazines** entity has it. I'm using this **@SqlResultSetMapping** as resultSetMapping for some native SQL query.

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(SQLStatements.CUSTOM_SQL_QUERY);
query.setResultMapping("BestSellerMagazinesJobQueryMapping");
query.list();
```

But i'm getting following exception while trying to execute this SQLQuery:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name ZoneId33_57_0_ is not valid.
```

So, Hibernate autogenerates a name for the **zoneId** field and tries to find this field in values which are returned by SQLQuery. 
Could i somehow tell Hibernate to ignore **zoneId** field in the **BestSellerMagazinesJobQueryMapping** mapping?

Comment: Could you please post your `SQLStatements.CUSTOM_SQL_QUERY`?

Comment: @Isank, the `SQLStatements.CUSTOM_SQL_QUERY` is something like `SELECT ID, GroupID from Magazines where TYPE = ?`

Comment: Hibernate always requires all columns which are not annotated with `@Transient`. If you only want to have a few fields filled, you could use a custom `ResultTransformer` or the hibernate function `select new BestSellerMagazines(col1, col2, ...)`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, thanks for the information. I was afraid that i can do it only with custom ResultTransformer.

Comment: As mentioned, `select new BestSellerMagazines(col1, col2, ...)` should work as well. It simply requires an constructor with the fields you want to fill in as parameter

Comment: @iChrome, You can use a @ConstructoResult for more flexible mappings. 

`
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "BestSellerMagazinesJobQueryMapping", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = SomeCustomMapping.class, columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "groupId", type = Integer.class)
}) })
`